# How to translate "payment gateway" into Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

I've been pulling my hairs on this one. Here is an example to contextualize its usage:

> You have shipping and/or tax enabled on your **payment gateway** which makes "Show Total Price" enabled by default.

Other examples:

> Would you like to keep the products to be used with another **payment gateway**?
>
> Only after we receive a notification from the **payment gateway**.
>
> Setup your **payment gateway** and products.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen people use **"plataforma(s) de pagamento"**

> Examples of some well-known **payment gateways** in Brazil
>
> 1 - PayPal
>
> 2 – MoIP
>
> 3 – PagSeguro
>
> 4 – MercadoPago
>
> 5 – Cielo

Answer (score 0):

`Meio de pagamento` is what I see most often, but, if *gateway* is a two-way payment method, I think `plataforma de pagamento` is a better fit.